# vfork() implicit declaration

Tags: c, vfork

I working in C with vfork(). My program working fine, but I have warning about implicit declaration.

My code:

```
if(vfork()==0){
...
}
```

My warning is:

*implicit declaration of function 'vfork' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration] if(vfork()==0){^*

I include those:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

If I use fork() and not vfork() warning gone. Soo problem is only vfork() in my program.
I don't know what this mean or how I fix that.

Comment: `#include` whatever file `vfork` is declared in. (looks like `<unistd.h>`)

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo  I have this include

Comment: try to `man vfork` and get the most accurate information.

Comment: Please excuse, but if you do not know what the warning you quote means, then trying to use `vfork()` won't make you happy ... - this is just a friendly hint ...

Answer (score 2):

You need to include these 2 headers:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

Also, add this line in the beginning of the program:

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
```

Comment: @NejcGalof What version of gcc? I don't get  that warning.

Comment: I have 4.8.2 version.

Comment: @NejcGalof Try adding #define _BSD_SOURCE

Comment: `vfork` is deprecated (it's been removed from the POSIX specification.)

Comment: If I use fork() and not vfork() warning gone. Soo problem is only vfork() in my program.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the required include files, then, depending on your system version, you may need to define some feature test macros. Please see documentation for your system (`man vfork` on unix-like systems)

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto Igor's answer, make sure you aren't compiling for C99. clang gives me the error "implicit declaration of function 'vfork' is invalid in C99", and removing `-std=c99` from the arguments fixed the issue.